# calculate difference of two datetime columns from two tables

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to calculate the difference of two `datetime` columns from two different tables

the values are like `2013-10-18 13:09:52.630`

I did like `select(a-b)` but it is not returning exact value. I want to calculate the number of days from above values. please give some suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, '2013-10-18 13:09:52.630', '2013-10-21 17:02:52.630')
```

which returns 3 for those dates.

If the first date is earlier than the 2nd date this will return a negative value (e.g. -2 days), you can wrap the `DATEDIFF` in an `ABS()` to make the value always positive.

For getting values from 2 tables:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, t1.Date, t2.Date) As DaysBetween
      ,ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, t1.Date, t2.Date)) As DaysBetweenAlwaysPositive
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Id
```

---

In regard to the comment:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(DiffMins / (60*24) AS VARCHAR) + 'days, ' 
    + CAST((DiffMins%(60*24))/60 AS VARCHAR) + 'hrs, ' 
    + CAST((DiffMins%(60*24))%60 AS VARCHAR) + 'mins ' AS dayhourmin
FROM (
SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '2013-10-18 13:09:52.630', '2013-10-19 15:12:52.630') AS DiffMins
) a
```

Outputs: `1days, 2hrs, 3mins`

This is all getting pretty messy, but you could use this in the 2 table query as follows:

```
SELECT CAST(DATEDIFF(DAY, t1.Date, t2.Date)/(60*24)     AS VARCHAR) + 'days, ' 
    + CAST((DATEDIFF(DAY, t1.Date, t2.Date)%(60*24))/60 AS VARCHAR) + 'hrs, ' 
    + CAST((DATEDIFF(DAY, t1.Date, t2.Date)%(60*24))%60 AS VARCHAR) + 'mins ' AS dayhourmin
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Id
```

This is a bigger question that your original one though so you may want to post a new one if this doesn't suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks,can you please tell this also,  i want to display the difference like 1Day 2hrs 3min.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF('2009-05-18 15:45:57.005678','2009-05-18 13:40:50.005670');
```

It works on mysql. I don know sql server 2008

Comment: sql server 2008 doesn't have a `TIMEDIFF` function.

Comment: I try to just give an idea. It has almost same syntax.Please Don't be arrogant

Comment: There's nothing arrogant about telling you that the function you are using doesn't exist in SQL Server. This is not a useful answer to the question asked. A small amount of research would have shown you valid [Date and Time Data Types and Functions (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx#GetDateandTimeDifference) before posting.

Comment: It s not about me. You should give this advice to user who asked this.